# Must I pay to dispose of bulky, unwanted deliveries?

Tags: united-states, shipping

I recently had a new refrigerator delivered, which unfortunately showed up with a dented door. The manufacturer sent me a new replacement door, and I scheduled a service appointment to have it installed. The problem is, the manufacturer then mistakenly sent me another refrigerator door. And then another.

The manufacturer won't take them back, and the service provider wouldn't take them. I'm left with several spare refrigerator doors which are bulky and difficult to dispose of. They don't fit in my regular trash pickup, so I'd have to pay for either bulk pickup, or pay to take them to the local transfer station.

I'm aware that goods delivered by mistake usually become the property of the recipient to do with whatever they please. But these goods are basically just trash that will cost me money to dispose of. Is there any recourse here to hold the sender responsible for the delivery? It strikes me as odd that they could force me to bear the cost of disposing of their mistake. In cases where a recipient does not want to keep mis-delivered goods, can the sender be forced to pay for return shipping, or cover disposal costs?

Comment: The (suburban) areas I've lived in the US offered (broken) appliance pickup like once a week or by appointment, free of charge. I'm rather sure they'll pick up just appliance doors too.

Comment: Why did you accept the deliveries rather than saying to the delivery driver "I don't want it, take it away"?

Comment: @DaleM They were on my front step when I arrived home, I had no opportunity to refuse delivery.

Answer (score 1):

### Can the sender be forced to pay for return shipping, or cover disposal costs?

Yes. The person you contracted with has clearly broken their contract and you can sue them for the resulting damages.

is it worth it? No.

Comment: What contract? The manufacturer agreed to send a new door and have a service provider install it, which they did. I don't understand who is supposed to have broken a contract, or what contract is supposed to have been broken by sending additional doors.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie the contract where you paid money for a fridge